# object is not update within map function and await too

Tags: node.js, api, express

Actually am getting details from cart table it display an array of objects , that object contains product id and quantity , after that i want to include price and name for my local display so i want to update the object for my reference, but name and price contains another table . here my code

````
exports.cartList = async (req, res) => {
    const CartId = req.profile.CartId;
    await Cart.findById(CartId).then(data => 
        {
           const products = data.products;
           const exprd = products;
           const length = products.length;
    
           exprd.map((item, index) => 
           { 
                const prodID = item.productId;
                const quantity = item.quantity;
    
                 Product.findById(prodID).then(prdDet => {
                    const price = prdDet.price;
                    const inven = prdDet.inventory;
                    const name = prdDet.name;
                    console.log(name);
                    console.log('CHECKERSP');
                    
                    if(quantity < inven)
                    {
                        ({ ...exprd, stock: 'stock',  })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ({ ...exprd, stock: 'Out of Stock',  })
                    }
                    
                    ({ ...exprd, name: name, price: price })
                });
                
                
                console.log('ex2',exprd);
           })
           console.log('ex1',exprd);
            
            res.json(exprd)
        });
}```
but object is not updated , i don't know what i did wrong because am very new to these things . Help me to overcome this problem, Thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 0):

First I think you have missed await before "Product.findById(prodID)"

Further,
In if and else block you have to assign the value after declaration.

Example:
let obj ={name:'XYZ'};

Either it should be:
let obj1 = {...obj, name:'ABC'};
Or
obj = {...obj, name:'ABC'};

Furthermore, If you are doing await inside a loop,
traditional loops are better. Map, filter and all can be tricky and await might not act as desired.

Kindly let me know if there is anything missing or wrong...
Just working things according to the funny experiences I acquired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: only one await is allowed to use , this is the error shows